# Upload the file from my local via Sauce Labs REST API

Tags: curl, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink, saucelabs

I am trying to upload the file from my local via **[Saucelabs REST API](https://saucelabs.com/docs/rest#storage/)** and using the following curl command for upload the file. What is the Uploaded file path in saucelabs?  How to use the special URL file format **"sauce-storage:your_file_name"** for testing

> curl -u  SAUCE_USERNAME: SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY -X POST
>   "http://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/ SAUCE_USERNAME
>   /imagefile.jpg?overwrite=true"  –H   "Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream" --data-binary @D:/ imagefile .jpg

Then I got the response  output like

> ‘{"username": " SAUCE_USERNAME ", "size": 615651, "md5":
>   "d156965b4d96ea9780a4892c25dc8c4a", "filename": " imagefile.jpg"}’

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this feature of Sauce Labs, but the way I understood the documentation was that you need to have the system under test to reference that file in the following way. Assuming that this is how your typical image tag would look:

```
<img src="/static/images/imagefile.jpg" alt="This really big image file..." />
```

Instead would need to be referenced as:

```
<img src="sauce-storage:imagefile.jpg" alt="This really big image file..." />
```

Your build would need to be able to control what is prepended to the name of the image path for this functionality to work properly.

Static files are cached by Sauce if you're using the sauce tunnel, so while this image is large at 600KB, you may not need to worry about uploading it initially, as it won't be pulled down again unless you shut the tunnel down.

Comment: Where the uploaded files are located in Saucelabs temporary storage?  What is this URL mean http://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/SAUCE_USERNAME/imagefile.jpg ?  I want the uploaded file path in saucelabs.  Because of sauce labs does not accept the files directly from my local system when I try to upload an image using form input file field via the behat testing.

Comment: I've been out of town, so my apologies for the delayed response. You aren't supposed to need to know where the file lives, they take care of the mapping when that bit is encountered in the HTML retrieved. The URL in question is telling sauce that you are uploading an image, and it will be created in a special bucket for your user name. You're test shouldn't need to know exactly where that file exists on sauce labs' servers. Have you tried their support / forums?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -u "$SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY" --location --request POST 'https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/v1/storage/upload' --form 'payload=@"<file path>"'
```

Provided the upload command for EU-CENTRAL Data Center.

Need to update the sauce lab storage url based on the data center.